# Jquery UI script tag error

Tags: html, jquery-ui

```
<head>
    <title>Mary</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://localhost/mary/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jscript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"/>
</head>
```

I just got done learning about jquery ui and am trying to include it in my very first webpage, but it's not working.  I checked all of the links on my server, and they link up to the documentation, but the only way the content shows up when I check the webpage on my server is if I comment out the last script tag.  But if I do that, I can't access the jquery ui, right?  I'm so confused.  I'm so excited to try all of this stuff out, but I can't figure out how to make it work :( Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this on localhost or a remote server? Either way, I'd recommend using relative paths instead of hardcoding localhost.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: local host right now.  I'm using a WAMP server.  I got a raspberryPi for my birthday, but I don't have time to learn how to use it yet.  Once I master this stuff, it's next.  I don't really know how to use relative paths yet for a local server, so I figured I would just do what I know how to do first, but from what I understand, it's basically using a shortcut to a path already written above it, right?

Comment: I don't get any errors at all.  I have divs that don't show up when I run it as is above, but they do show up when I comment out the last script tag.  I don't have any idea what could cause something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all the static files are properly referenced,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"/>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Note the end of the `script` tag `/>` should be `></script>`

Comment: let me try that!  Am I correct though in assuming that when I test it out by clicking the links they are working correctly if that takes me to the page that it's linked to or is that a poor assumption because I'm clicking on the link and there could be an error elsewhere in the script tag?

Comment: IT WORKED!  I can't believe I missed that!  thank you so so so much!

Comment: Yes.. that is a good way to test it. A smarter way would be to just see the browser's console to see if there are any console errors (404s)

Answer (score 1):

karthikr's answer is most likely the problem, but if that doesn't work try referencing the URL hosted by jquery itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Is this considered a best practice?

Comment: Not usually. It's best to download the actual file to your server so there isn't extra loading time for the user to get the file from another server.

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  That makes much more sense to me.